# Integrating Twitter bootstrap with Wild Apricot's theme overrides

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Has anyone done this integration or have a tutorial recommendation?  They have kind of a quirky "override" method in order to actually modify the HTML:

http://help.wildapricot.com/display/DOC/Theme+overrides

Bootstrap is a familiar platform to me, where their default HTML skeleton is less so.  Certainly, the most useful would be if someone could point me to an existing snippet getting started.

Answer (score 0):

There's no easy solution to this.  WA uses a different template language, and you'll have to examine class names manually and compare differences to shove the two together.